# Git hub file path in batch command-Jenkins

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins, github, webpagetest

Im implementing Webpagetest api using script insteads of passing url along with the command.

Instead of

```
 webpagetest test "www.example.com" -k XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I use `webpagetest test "D:\Jmeter\WebPageTestAPI\webpagetestApiMaster\test\fixtures\script.txt" -k XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

script contains `www.example.com`

Im now implementing https://github.com/marcelduran/webpagetest-api.git

can anyone tell me how can i pass `/webpagetest-api/tree/master/test/fixtures/script.txt` as i used above. in command when i have github repo.

when i tried

```
webpagetest test "https://github.com/marcelduran/webpagetest-api/tree/master/test/fixtures/script.txt" -k XXXXXXX
```

the data in script.txt is not used..insted `https://github.com/marcelduran/webpagetest-api/tree/master/test/fixtures/script.txt` itself was considered as URL.

Hope my question is clear ..if not please let me know.